# Coding multiples that equal 100

Tags: java, beginner, array

The objective was to see what numbers can be multiplied to equal 100.

Example:

```
1 x 1 = 1 //no match
5 x 20 = 100 //match
```

The objective (as I'm learning) was only to use an array as I wanted to practice how it functioned. There are probably other classes I could have used which would have been better, for example, an `ArrayList` to store a match rather than an array defined of [100].

I'm pretty new to programming and would like your opinion on my following block of code.

```
public class ArraySearchTest
{

    public ArraySearchTest()
    {
        doTest();
    }

    public void doTest()
    {
        int [] array = new int[100];
        int [] bbb = new int[11];
        int [] ans = new int[100];

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            for(int p = 0; p < bbb.length; p++)
            {
                if( p * i == 100)
                {
                    ans[p] = (p + i);
                    System.out.println(p + " x " + i + " Equals 100");
                }   
            }     
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### General Style:

Use functions where you can. You have embedded all the code in to one method.

For many reasons, you should create a function which takes the 100 value as a parameter. Additionally, the purpose of the code is to return pairs of numbers that have 100 as the product, so what you want is a container to store each pair.

This is a start to turning your code in to Object Oriented code.

### Classes (OOP)

A container for a result, which is two values that multiply to the target, would be called something like CoFactors (Factors which together make the target). It would look something like:

```
public class CoFactor {
    private final int lesser, greater;

    public CoFactor(int lesser, int greater) {
        this.lesser = lesser;
        this.greater = greater;
    }

    public int getLesser() {
        return lesser;
    }

    public int getGreater() {
        return greater;
    }
}
```

### Algorithm

Now, with that class, we can return the factors of a number with a method like:

```
public static final List<CoFactor> getCoFactors(int target) {
    ....
}
```

The above method will return a list of factors that have the target as a product.

How would that be coded? First, some math....

- each factor of a number has a partner (perhaps, if the number is a square number, the partner is itself (`3 x 3 = 9` for example) The lesser factor will only be smaller when the lesser factor is less than the square-root of the target....
- each small factor has a partnering large factor, and there is only one partner.
- we only need to find the small ones to also be able to find the large ones.
- we can tell if a number is a factor if there's no remainder after a division (use the `%` modulo operator)

This can be computed as:

```
List<CoFactor> factors = new ArrayList<>();
int root = (int)Math.sqrt(target);
for (int attempt = 1; attempt <= root; i++) {
    if (target % attempt == 0) {
        factors.add(new CoFactor(attempt, target / attempt));
    }
}
return factors;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have noticed you have used getters/setters in the first class and have used a second class to create an array which will then calculate the numbers and look for a remainder. If a remainder exists then it won't be added to the array.

Your method seems clever (and a little complicated to me to get my head around!) but I will give it a try.

Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 7):

> PS. the objective (as I'm learning) was only to use an array as I wanted to practice how it functioned.

You lost me. You're using 3 arrays, but two are essentially unused and the third gets only written, never read. So you could drop them all.

```
public class ArraySearchTest
{
```

In Java the brace belongs on the previous line.

```
int [] array = new int[100];
```

Write `int[] array` as the type is `int[]`, so it belongs together.

---

After dropping the arrays, not much is left.... I'd suggest to modify the task, so that an array gets really needed. The simplest possibility is probably

> For a given two equally long arrays, compute how many pairs multiply to 100.

The building of the pairs is ambiguous, so these are actually 2 different tasks.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class FactorFinder
{
    //research "Magic Numbers" for my reasoning on adding this.
    private final int DEFAULTNUMBER = 100

    //Pass in any integer to find it's factors (not just 100)
    public FactorFinder(int number) 
    {       
        printFactors(number); //more descriptive than doTest()
    }

    //Default constructor, use DEFAULTNUMBER to do the calculation
    public FactorFinder()
    {
        printFactors(DEFAULTNUMBER);
    }


    //changed name from doTest() to printFactors(int number)
    public static void printFactors(int number)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i <= number / 2; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) //changed p to j.
            {
                if( i * j == number)
                {
                    System.out.println(j + " x " + i + " Equals 100");
                    break; //This breaks out of the inner loop.
                }
                else if(i * j > number){
                    //If the product is greater than the number,
                    //there is no need to continue calculating,
                    //break out of the inner loop
                    break;
                }
            }     
        }
    }
}
```

Things that I did:

- Made your code work for any positive integer you pass in, other than 100.
- Made 100 the default number in-case you did not specify the number.
- Improved the efficiency of the loop.  If you do the math, everything should check out:

  - started index at `1` because `0 x number = 0` :  wasted loop time
  - Outer loop: `(i < number / 2)`  :  do the math and think about why I did this.
  - loop: (j <= i) :  This will eliminate double calculations
  - 20 X 5 = 100 and 5 X 20 = 100  (This depends on the problem though)
  - added <strike>continue</strike> break statements that leave the **inner** loop if the product is greater.

Comment: There's no point in constructing an object. Just make `printFactors(number)` a static function.